# Does a source for words pertaining to programming or software development exist?

Tags: resources, programming

The only words that I've seen that can be used to refer unambiguously to software development are general ones, like *programi* and *programisto*, and (originally) mathematical terms such as *variablo*.

But I'm at a loss as to what words I'd use to express anything more technical than that. Does a comprehensive list of technical development terms exist?

Comment: The Linux translations like of Ubuntu contain many software and hardware related terms like for commit/rollback, query. Hardly comprehensive though.

Answer (score 20):

Yes! The most comprehensive resource for technical language is [*Komputeko*](http://komputeko.net), an online dictionary run by E@I. It's comprised of a large number of neologisms, some of which are pulled from other sources (the largest probably being [*Komputada Leksikono*](http://bertilow.com/div/komputada_leksikono/)). Some of these neologisms are derived from English terms (English being the lingua franca of tech), but most are derived from Esperanto roots.

Answer (score 8):

Franclingve ekzistas *Lexique des termes scientifiques
Mathématique, physique, informatique, français-esperanto, esperanto-français* far Jacques Joguin. Mi ne konas retumeblan version, sed mi aĉetis la paperan version, kaj ofte uzas ĝin komplemente al aliaj fontoj kiel Komputeko. Mi opinias ke se vi konas franclingvon kaj interesas pri scienco, ĝi estas aĉetinda libro.

Por vere matematika termoj, ankaŭ ekzistas [Matematika vortaro kaj oklingva leksikono](https://www.academia.edu/7296209/Matematika_vortaro_kaj_oklingva_leksikono_book_) far Marc Bavant.

Mi mem tradukis [Javascript termojn por la Babylcript projekto](http://www.babylscript.com/mappings/eo.html), kaj vi ankaŭ povas konsulti [la dokumenton, kiu provizas pli da detaloj kaj aliaj ebloj de traduko por tiuj termoj](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZdKCDKyz_6B9Aqbkd3ebCfcVOeX-ojN6li0yUbKpUkg/edit#gid=0). Mi egale plene tradukis [la erarajn mesaĝojn](https://docs.google.com/document/d/15M4ywbNCTScjbDd7Jl_lelOIkj2SRgo5SHaPkBLvGTE/edit), kie mi egale proponas kaj priskribas tradukajn elektojn. Kvankam Babylscript estas pri Javascript, mi egale traktas aliajn programlingvojn simbolojn (ŝlosilvortoj). Vi povas konsulti [mian deponejon](http://github.com/psychoslave/babylscript/).

Mi egale komencis traduki Lua en la [Lupa projekto](https://github.com/psychoslave/lupa), kaj vi trovos tradukojn por ĉiuj ĝiaj simboloj en [la vikio](https://github.com/psychoslave/lupa/wiki). Estas ankoraŭ multe da laboro tie, ĉar mi ŝatus traduki esperante kaj la programlingvo (sed resti kongrua kun plena Lua 5.3 kodo) kaj la dokumentaro. Estus perfekte se mi povos tute rekodi tiun esperante, aŭ per Lupa implementado, aŭ per ne ankoraŭ ekzistan esperanta C-ekvivalento (tio estas, kiel esperanta ASM, ankoraŭ necesas kreadon). Bonvenon estas ĉiu helpo, ne hezitu kontakti min se ajn antaŭa projekto interesas vin. :)